# How to expand input field to the right in a header bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a header bar with left-aligned items, center items and right-aligned items. In the center, I have multiple items and a search input field. When the search field gets focus, I'm making it wider by animating the width. Right now, because the items are centered, it's animating both left and right to center the content. How can I change this so it keeps the alignment and expands the width to the right?

I'm not using Bootstrap.
I'm currently using a table for the header bar content. I'm open to changing that, but if there's a way to do it with the current design, that would be preferred.

Here's a JSFiddle...click in the search field to see what's happening: https://jsfiddle.net/L60g0j64/1/

EDIT: I've updated it with the suggested solution below. My only issue is that the red container surrounding the input should expand also.

HTML/CSS/JS Snippet

```js
$('#search').focus(function() {
  $(this).val("");
  $('#hidden_content').css('display','inline');
  $(this).animate({width: '180px'}, 200);
});

$('#search').blur(function() {
  $(this).val('Search');
  $('#hidden_content').css('display','none');
  $(this).animate({width: '120px'}, 200);
});
```

```css
.header-navbar {
cursor: pointer;
white-space: nowrap;
background-color: #1f2127;
color: #cbcbcb;
min-width: 0;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
z-index: 299;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 32px;
float: none;
position: fixed;
border-spacing: 0px;
}
td.cell-center {
text-align: center;
}
.cell-center table {
margin: 0 auto;
}
.header-table {
height: 32px;
border: none;
border-spacing: 0px;
}
td.header_rtd {
padding-right:12px;
}
td.header_ltd {
padding-left:12px;
}
.search-wrapper {
  max-width: 124px;
  background-color: red;
  padding:4px;
}
.hidden_content{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="header-navbar" id="header" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
<tr>
  <td>
    <table class="header-table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class='header_rtd'>left1</td>
          <td class='header_rtd'>left2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>        
  </td>
  <td width=100% class='cell-center'>
    <table class="header-table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class='header_rtd'>center</td>
          <td class='header_rtd'>center</td>
          <td><div class="search-wrapper">
            <input class="search" id="search" style="width: 120px;" type="text" size="60" value="Search"/>
            <div class='hidden_content' id='hidden_content'>
              hidden content
            </div>
            </div></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>                
  </td>
  <td>
    <table class="header-table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class='header_ltd'>right1</td>
          <td class='header_ltd'>right2</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>        
  </td>
</tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One quick solution would be to give the parent element a `max-width` equal to the initial width of the element. In doing so, the element will still be centered relative to the initial width because the `input` element's animated width will not effect the width of the parent element.

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/vwg3fczc/)

```
.search-wrapper {
  max-width: 124px;
}
```

As a side note, you don't need jQuery/JS to animate the width, you can simply use a CSS transition along with the [`:focus` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Afocus).

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/5o0ktkan/)

```
.search-wrapper input.search {
  transition: 1s width ease;
  width: 120px;
}
.search-wrapper input.search:focus {
  width: 180px;
}
```

Comment: Your first solution looks like what I want but just curious, why are you using 124px?

Comment: @ChaseRocker To account for the `1px` padding/border on each side (`1px`*`4` === `4px`)... `120px` => `124px`. I guess you could add `box-sizing: border-box` to account for that though. It's up to you.

Comment: ok, that's what I thought, just wanted to make sure. Thanks for the help!

Comment: After trying your solution, there's actually an additional issue. In my example, I stripped out some of the other stuff I'm doing, but when I use your suggestion, it doesn't quite work because I'm actually also displaying the container...it has a different background color. Which means it needs to expand also. It also contains a hidden div which I'm showing and hiding. Can you take a look at the updated JSFiddle above?  thnx

Comment: Close...Can you get the hidden content in it also? The container is actually a themed rounded border container and inside it are icons, the search input and an additional combo box (the hidden field).

Comment: ok, I see what you're doing there...I believe I can work with that. Thanks for the help.